# Finding the limit with three variables

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Here is the original problem: 
$$\lim_{(x,y,z)\to (0,0,0)}{(\cos x-1)\sin(2y)(e^{3z}-1)\over x^2yz}$$
I was thinking about splitting up the limit like this:
$$\lim_{(x,y,z)\to (0,0,0)}{(\cos x-1)\over x^2}\cdot\lim_{(x,y,z)\to (0,0,0)}{\sin(2y)\over y}\cdot\lim_{(x,y,z)\to (0,0,0)}{e^{3z}-1\over z}$$
And then break it down some more:$$\lim_{x\to 0}{(\cos x-1)\over x^2}\cdot\lim_{y\to 0}{\sin(2y)\over y}\cdot\lim_{z\to 0}{e^{3z}-1\over z}$$
And then I want to use L'Hospital's rule. If someone could let me know if I'm heading in the right direction or not, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Yes it's a right direction.

Comment: Something is a little funny, because this function is not defined on any of the coordinate planes, so in particular, not on a punctured neighborhood of $(0,0,0)$

Comment: @PinkElephants I think that the function is well defined on the coordinates planes minus the coordinate axis: for example, a Taylor expansion in $x$ gives $-0.5f(y,z)+O(x^2 f(y,z))$, which is well behaved in the limit $x\rightarrow 0$ is both $y$ and $z$ stay away from zero. If not, one needs to consider the other Taylor expansions, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{(x,y,z)\to (0,0,0)}{(\cos x-1)\sin(2y)(e^{3z}-1)\over x^2yz}$$
I was thinking about splitting up the limit like this:
$$\lim_{(x,y,z)\to (0,0,0)}{(\cos x-1)\over x^2}\cdot\lim_{(x,y,z)\to (0,0,0)}{\sin(2y)\over y}\cdot\lim_{(x,y,z)\to (0,0,0)}{e^{3z}-1\over z}$$
And then break it down some more:$$\lim_{x\to 0}{(\cos x-1)\over x^2}\cdot\lim_{y\to 0}{\sin(2y)\over y}\cdot\lim_{z\to 0}{e^{3z}-1\over z}$$
LH rule to the first part gives you (-0.5) 

Second part ofcourse gives you 2 by multiplying dividing by 2 and cancelling sin 2y/2y
Third part again use LH rule to get 3.
Multiply all three  parts to eventually get an  **ANSWER -3**

Answer (score 1):

If all the limits in sight exist, you're fine.

Comment: On the contrary, when going to step 2 to step 3, OP isn't making any restrictions regarding the path taken. $$\lim_{(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)}\frac{\cos x -1}{x^2} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos x -1}{x^2}$$ regardless of which path is chosen, since the other variables do not appear in the expression. A similar argument can be made for the remaining terms.

Comment: Ah, I see. Took me a while to see what you were getting at. Since the other variables don't appear, the manner in which they approach the origin is independent of the others, so they could be related or not. I'll change my answer accordingly.

Comment: Hahaha, thanks guys! Yeah, my limit came out to be -3, which matches the answer on my review sheet.

Answer (score 1):

One more way: use Maclaurin series expansion for all three functions in the numerator:
$$
\cos x =1+O(x^2)\\
\sin y = y+O(y^3)\\
e^z=1+O(z)
$$

Lots of terms cancel out. Can you handle from here?

Comment: We haven't learned about series in multivariable calculus yet.

Comment: All your functions are single variable, i.e. you don't have $\log (x+y)$